# Declined invitation in future, how can I still see when it was originally scheduled?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, meetings, meeting-request

Secretary sends out months of meetings, always at a time I already have a re-occurring meeting, so I decline them all.
However, what if my meeting changes/ends and now I could attend if I wanted- how can I still see that I was invited to a meeting at that time- without replying "tentative" to them all?
Is there a way?

Comment: Why, specifically, is accepting tentative not a solution?

Comment: Accepted/Rejected calendar invites are placed in your Deleted folder.  If the meeting is changed then you will get an updated invitation since you were originally invited.

Answer (score 0):

You use the expression 'without replying tentative'. I can imagine that you want to reply and tell the meeting organiser that you declined the invite, but still show it on your calendar.

If the ***reply*** is the issue, then when you receive the invitation, decline it and send a response as usual. Then find the meeting request in your deleted items folder, and accept it as tentative. Choose 'Do Not Send A Response'.

This way, the meeting will be added to your calendar, but the organiser will be told that you have declined the meeting.